# How to load and show a video file flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-widget, flutter-video-player

I want to show a video in my website developed using flutter web, what the solution for this problem?

Note: Using video_player package doesn't work for file. VideoPlayerController.file() not implemented for flutter web.

**Thx for help!**

Comment: Can you share code snippet & error?  It might help better understand you issue